# NameError: name 'drive_service' is not defined Google API

Tags: python, google-api-client

I want to upload a photo to google drive. 
I can read the files that are on the drive. 
But when I ad the uploading part, from line 49 to 55, I keep getting the same error.
I keep getting the error "NameError: name 'drive_service' is not defined"
I have every library imported but still doesn't work
This is my code
I've looked around but haven't seen a post explaining it.

```
from __future__ import print_function
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from httplib2 import Http
from oauth2client import file, client, tools
from apiclient.http import MediaFileUpload



# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.json.
SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'

def main():
    """Shows basic usage of the Drive v3 API.
    Prints the names and ids of the first 10 files the user has access to."""
    # The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    store = file.Storage('token.json')
    creds = store.get()
    if not creds or creds.invalid:
        flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('credentials.json', SCOPES)
        creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store)
    drive = build('drive', 'v3', http=creds.authorize(Http()))

    # Call the Drive v3 API
    results = drive.files().list(
        pageSize=10, fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name)").execute()
    items = results.get('files', [])

    if not items:
        print('No files found.')
    else:
        print('Files:')
        for item in items:
            print(u'{0} ({1})'.format(item['name'], item['id']))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

file_metadata = {'name': 'photo.jpg'}
media = MediaFileUpload('photo.jpg',
                        mimetype='image/jpeg')
file = drive_service.files().create(body=file_metadata,
                                    media_body=media,
                                    fields='id').execute()
print ('File ID: %s' % file.get('id'))
```

Comment: Do you expect the name `drive_service` to be defined at that point? Why?

Comment: Well I followed the google tutorial but it doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 6):

you can directly use **service** instead of driver_service. It worked for me.

As shown in the code sample

```
file_metadata = {'name': 'photo.jpg'}
media = MediaFileUpload('photo.jpg',
                        mimetype='image/jpeg')
file = service.files().create(body=file_metadata,
                                    media_body=media,
                                    fields='id').execute()
```

Answer (score 5):

You have build your connection with this line:

`drive = build('drive', 'v3', http=creds.authorize(Http()))`

When calling `file = drive_service.files()`
you have to pass the connection you have just built. So instead of `drive_service`, use `drive` (that you have just built).

Summing up, you should replace:

```
file = drive_service.files().create(body=file_metadata,
                                    media_body=media,
                                    fields='id').execute()
```

with:

```
file = drive.files().create(body=file_metadata,
                            media_body=media,
                            fields='id').execute()
```

and your script should work.

Answer (score 3):

Change `drive_service` to `drive` or vise versa